# Anyone uses the ZOOM meetup software with eOS?

Tags: applications

I use the Zoom videoconferencing software quite a bit. It works great on Mac OS and on Ubuntu 18.04. On eOS, however, the picture freezes two seconds into the meeting, or the camera is no longer detected and it sends my fan into hyperventilation. Does anyone use Zoom successfully with eOS? 
Thanks!
Fred

Answer (score 1):

No issues here -

```
$ cat /etc/*release            
DISTRIB_ID=elementary
DISTRIB_RELEASE=5.0
DISTRIB_CODENAME=juno
```

updated as of this morning.

Using Zoom latest directly from site. I zoom a few times a day for work, can share, am able to control and see. I did have an issue one day where slack and zoom were being controlled by the same dock icon, for some reason it recorded both pids so I just restarted and it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks, so you just use zoom from your browser, instead of the app?